# Graph with chromatic number $4$ that is not a supergraph of $K_3$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I've been trying to find a graph in which the chromatic number is equal to $4$ but it cannot be a supergraph of $K_3$.

I tried with an $11$-gon and join vertices every two vertices, (excuse me If my explanation is not clear, I'm learning English) anyway the resulting graph has chromatic number equal to $3$ and I thought that it was going to be the same with every cyclic graph.

Any examples?

Thanks.

Comment: Why tag this question with `planar-graphs`?

Comment: Your Question would be improved by adding context.  It's present form, that of a bare problem statement without context, is disfavored by the Math.SE community.  You could give a report of your own efforts to construct such a graph and where you met with difficulty, or you could explain why the problem is important or interesting to you.  And there are many other ways to supply context, something that would allow Readers to respond in useful detail congruent with your level of study.

Comment: Dude, what do you want from me? I'm just trying to learn some math by myself, I'm posting the problem exactly as the book says, I'm pretty sure that these questions are easy for a lot of people here. Not everything has to be "relevant for the community", some people just want help with a book problem, maybe others want to solve really hard stuff, I'm not one of them.

Comment: Smallest one is the [Grötzsch graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroetzschGraph.html).

Comment: That's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Start with a $13$-gon.  For each independent triple of vertices $\{a,b,c\}$in the $13$-gon, add a vertex $v_{\{a,b,c\}}$ and edges connecting $v_{\{a,b,c\}}$ to each of $a,b,c$.  Call the resulting graph $K$.

Here by *independent triple of vertices* we mean three distinct vertices in the polygon, none of which are connected by an edge of the polygon.

Then $K$ is $4$-colourable: simply $3$-colour the $13$-gon, and colour all the $v_{\{a,b,c\}}$ with the fourth colour.

Also $K$ is triangle free: the $13$-gon is triangle free, so a triangle would have to involve a vertex $v_{\{a,b,c\}}$.  However ${\{a,b,c\}}$ are independent, so there is no such triangle.  Thus $K$ is not a supergraph of $K_3$.

It remains to show that $K$ is not $3$-colourable.  Suppose we have a $3$-colouring of $K$. Then for any independent triple ${\{a,b,c\}}$ of vertices in the polygon, they cannot all be different colours, as that would leave no choice of colour for $v_{\{a,b,c\}}$.

Pick a vertex $x$ in the polygon.  Call its colour $c_1$.  Opposite $x$ is an edge, with at least one end vertex not coloured $c_1$.  Call this vertex $y$, and its colour $c_2$.  Let $c_3$ denote the remaining colour.

Now the only vertices that may be coloured $c_3$ are the four vertices adjacent to $x,y$, as if any other vertex $a$ were coloured $c_3$, then ${\{x,y,a\}}$ would be an independent triple all coloured differently, which cannot happen.

Conversely, at least one of those four vertices must be coloured $c_3$, as a $13$-gon is not $2$-colourable.  Call this vertex $z$.

Now if we exclude $x,y$, the four vertices adjacent to them, which may be coloured $c_3$, and the remaining four vertices adjacent to those, we are left with one vertex $u$ on one side of the polygon, and two adjacent vertices $v,w$ on the other.

[image]

All three of $u,v,w$ are coloured by $c_1$ or $c_2$.  As $v, w$ cannot be the same colour, one of them must be coloured differently to $u$.  Thus $\{u,v,z\}$ or $\{u,w,z\}$ are an independent triple, all coloured differently, which cannot happen.

We conclude that $K$ is not $3$-colourable.

Comment: Thanks, I'm curious about how you get to the answer, I tried with an 11-gon and join vertices every two vertices, (excuse me If my explanation is not clear, I'm learning English) anyway the resulting graph has chromatic number equal to 3 and I thought that it was going to be the same with every Cyclic graph. Thanks for answering the question, now I can continue with the next one.

Comment: My thought process started exactly the same as you.   I thought of starting with a polygon and adding "diagonal" edges.  Like you, I got nowhere with this.  Then I thought of adding new vertices, connected to triples of vertices from the polygon, so that those triples could not all be different colours.  Then  I thought if I am doing that, I might as well add all the ones which do not create a triangle.

Comment: The people on this site like some "human context" in the questions.  I think you put everything they want in the comments.  Do you mind if I copy and paste your comments into the main question? This should make everyone happy.

Comment: Thanks man! You know how to approach a newbie, and I'm sad I didn't continue with that approach, lesson learned, don't give up that easily. I'll add the context